# How to fix ubuntu 12.10 brightness and lock icon

Tags: brightness, lock

When clicking on the brightness and lock icon, the system settings just closes but never open brightness and lock.

Comment: Did you try opening the app 'Brightness and Lock' from your Dash?

Comment: yes, how do i fix it with terminal

Comment: Could you be more specific, I got no idea what you do to trigger that. [edit] your question, add some details about your system, what are you trying to do, and how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from your terminal, first install gnome control center :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-control-center
```

After you can start system setting app :

```
gnome-control-center
```